# Creating a Plugin System with Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I have been looking into how to create a plugin system with Phalcon. I have checked INVO tutorial, [Events Management](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-invo.html#events-management) to be more specific. It doesn't look like this is what I exactly need.

In this [example](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial-invo.html#events-management) it is loading the plugins manually and before establishing database connection.

1. I need to be able to access the database to check if the plugin actually installed and activated. So I can retrieve settings of installed & activated plugins as well as dynamically add them to the app.
2. I need to be able to attach the plugins pretty much anywhere; controllers (before / after / within method execution), models (before, after, within method execution) etc.

Does Phalcon provide such feature or do I have to ahead and try to create my own logic without using any framework feature?

Comment: Hi, I would go with simple PDO query for retrieving plugin names from DB to load before running your app `new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application();`. Beside that I don't know any such feature.

Comment: @jodator yes, I'm guessing I will have to go ahead and create my own logic here!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any examples of what you would have plugins do? Or specifics about where Events Management is lacking?

I think you should be able able to get a very flexible system using dependency injection and events management.

It appears you can use the phalcon models before running the application, as long as you place the code after setting the db in the injector.

```
$plugins = \Plugin::find([
    'active = :active:',
    'bind'=>[
        'active'=>1
    ]
]);

foreach($plugins as $plugin){
    if(file_exists($plugin->filename)){
       include $plugin->filename;
    }
}
```

and in the file you could have code to subscribe to events, and/or add new dependencies.

```
// plugin file - for a db logger
$eventsManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();
$logger = new \PhalconX\Logger\Adapter\Basic();
$profiler = $phalconDi->getProfiler();
$eventsManager->attach('db', function($event, $phalconConnection) use ($logger, $profiler) {
    if ($event->getType() == 'beforeQuery') {
        $profiler->startProfile($phalconConnection->getSQLStatement());
        $logger->log($phalconConnection->getSQLStatement(), \Phalcon\Logger::INFO, $phalconConnection->getSQLVariables());
    }
    if ($event->getType() == 'afterQuery') {
        $profiler->stopProfile();
    }
});
```

or

```
class myHelper{ ... }

$phalconDi->set('myHelper', function() use ($phalconConfig, $phalconDi) {
    $helper = new myHelper();
    $helper->setDi( $phalconDi );
    return $helper;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You can also do it with extending your class to Phalcon's Component class. This way you don't have to pass PhalconDI and you can directly access it as if you would from controller using `$this`. At the moment I'm just looking for a good logic where I don't need to touch the core app files. Instead I should be able to do everything directly from plugin's file. I didn't have to time play around much yet though.